# From terminal to normal mode and run a command

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-buffer

I have the following mapping

```
tnoremap <F8> <c-w>N :Vista!!<CR>
```

but the command after `<c-w>N` (in my case `:Vista!!`) is not executed.
How should I fix it?

Comment: See `:help t_CTRL-W_:` for a possibly better alternative to `<C-w>N`.

Comment: It's unlikely to be the cause of your problem, but it should be noted that the space you've entered between `<c-w>N` and `:Vista` is unnecessary and in fact actively harmful: it will be executed as part of the mapping, [moving your cursor to the right](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#l) if it can (and stopping the mapping if it can't).